# Check more as one value in a json file with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

i trying to check more values in the ids object. I want to check it later in python with the if funktion. so if 8080 or 884481 in the file then do stuff.

Json file:

```
        "ids": {
            "1": 84481,
            "2": 8080,
        }
```

my code is at time so

```
    async def get_data(self):
        with open("test.json", "r") as f:
            users = json.load(f)

            return users

     async def test
        users = await self.get_data()
        x= 8080
        user = 00000
        id = users["ids"]
        if x == id
            # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment, what you have is a `users` variable, which is a dict such as :

```py
{"ids": {"1": 84481, "2": 8080}}  # users
```

Once you extract the `ids` key, you get a new dict, which is your `id` variable :

```py
{"1": 84481, "2": 8080}  # id = users["ids"]
```

You then cannot just check `x == id` as you are doing since you are comparing an int with a dictionnary.

Moreover your code is currently seeking for an int, which are the values of your dict. I would suggest that you invert your dictionnary as :

```py
new_ids = {value: key for key, value in id.items()}
# Look like {84481: "1", 8080: "2"}
```

Now you just have to check that the `new_ids` has a key matching the `x` you are looking for :

```py
if x in new_ids.keys():
    # Do stuff beacause you found a matching
    key = new_ids[x]   # With x = 8080, key = "2"
else:
    # Do other stuff because found no matching
```